# How can I make sure my sending username and password combination is correct without grabbing the whole html page in php cURL?

Tags: php, curl, forms-authentication, php-curl

I am trying to login a remote login form using php cURL by sending username and password with **CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS** value. This is for an experiment.

The cURL configuration code is given below -

```
    $username = myname;
    $password = '1323';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://localhost/Hackalgo/DummySite/login.php');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
'username='.$username.'&password='.$password);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
```

I have ensured that **CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER** option is **0** because I need not get the whole html page to grab I just need to confirm the password.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
```

But when I execute the commands I am getting always true even if I passed wrong password and username combination too.

```
 $result = curl_exec($ch);
 var_dump($result);
```

Which return value of ***curl_exec($ch)*** will ensure me that my sending username and password is correct or not for this authentication in login form or otherwise how can I do this ?

You may suggest me any other way to do this.

*Thanks in advance.*

Comment: unless the third party site returns a 3xx class error and always returns 200 ok, you will never know without inspecting the content of the page. If there's a session in play you may be able to leverage session/cookie data, but you'll still need to fetch a html page that hints at the user being logged in.

Comment: Use the codeception for this kind of activity.

Comment: I have solved this another way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options.

1)
use CURLOPT_USERPWD except of CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS

2)
send is as properly formatted Content-Type (as target requires) for example send json

`$params = [
  "username" => $username,
  "passwd" => $passwd,
];`

`$json = json_encode($params);`

`curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);`